# Should we limit review amount a user can do per day?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, flags

I have come to learn that there is a system which gives *n* amount of flags depending on how much reputation points you earned or how many helpful flags you raised.

---

[image: help-center: flags per day]

---

I have access to Triage, First posts and Late answers. I have reviewed a total of 30 reviews. I earned two extra flags doing it. Having done all my reviews for the day, I cannot help improving/flagging the posts. **I don't quite understand why limiting flags for reviewers is helping the website?** I read somewhere that flags weren't much flooded with bad reviews so that shouldn't be the reason.

I understand, though, that flagging posts and comments (outside of reviews) is *not* a privilege therefore giving 10 flags is acceptable considering that the new users don't necessarily know what are the rules and how to enforce them. Shouldn't users with enough reputation points be able to review more posts/answers, as long that their reviews are *indeed* helpful?

### What do I propose

- Allow users with reviewing privileges to do more, as long as they have a positive reviewing ratio.

That means that the flags wouldn't influence the reviewing privilege with limiting how many reviews a user can do per day. As I am writing this, there is 85 Triage reviews on the list, but I have to wait for tomorrow to do only 12 more... I cannot flag comments or posts either anymore for being inappropriate because I have done my *part* as a community member of Stack Overflow with the reviews for the day. Is letting a bad question/answer/comment stand appropriate?

I want to focus on the fact that the goal is **not** going for volume. Going through 12 flags when there is over 80 reviews waiting for a vote, it can easily get done with reviewing First posts and Late answers. They are more than often too broad or off-topic and such.

Comment: You *flag* every post you review in Triage? That's seem to be inappropriate even for amount of low quality content we get...

Comment: I do not, but between `Looks OK` and `Skip`, I can easily flag 12 posts/answers when I go through more than 80 `Triage` reviews laying there.

Comment: There have been numerous requests for us to increase the amount of reviews we can do (or specifically to double the # of CVs we get to use in the queue or at least split out our queue CVs from organic CVs), to no avail.

Comment: Well this is too bad. I just wanted to contribute more and seeing that there is enough reviews in the list, I just thought that *doing more* would actually be helpful for the quality of the website overall.

Comment: Note that the name of the queues are not code and should not be formatted as such. Code formatting should not be used as emphasis either. Please remember this while you review as well :).

Comment: An other solution is Reach 3K and get vote instead of flag.

Comment: Not being well-formatted is not a reason to flag. It's a reason to edit...

Comment: I am indeed editing the not well formated posts since I am trying to get the editor badge.

Answer (score 5):

...nah.

You shouldn't be going for volume on reviews.  You should be going for quality of reviews.  Giving you the ability to do more greatly expands the former and makes the latter near impossible to quantify.

Comment: "You shouldn't be going for volume on reviews." might be the single best advice for reviews. Can we edit it in to the badges descriptions?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, the goal is not to go for volume. My point was **I want to help** more. I can see my suggestion is not well received so I will simply do my ten ish votes a day until I earn more flags.

Comment: @pensum:  Reviewing slowly and with purpose is more help than you realize.  I can get that you want to help more, but "more" is borne out of "quantity" in your suggestion.  That's not what we need.

Comment: @Makoto I one hundred percent agree with you. I spent at least half an hour trying to support my suggestion and I guess I still failed to do so. I didn't think I had to specify that doing 10 reviews can take only a few minutes of your day so doing more doesn't mean rushing it to me.